# sql Sum calculation

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below query..

```
 Select Emp_key,date_key,
 ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN Amt_2 <> 0 THEN Amt_1/ Amt_2 END),4) AS Net_Amt 
 from Salary
 group by Emp_key,date_key;
```

what result does this query give?

```
1.Sum[(Amt_1/ Amt_2) + (Amt_1/ Amt_2) + (Amt_1/ Amt_2) + (Amt_1/ Amt_2) + ......]
```

or

```
2.Sum(Amt_1) / Sum(Amt_2)
```

I want my `Net_Amt` to be `Sum(Amt_1) / Sum(Amt_2)`

Comment: Both should give same result; Mathematically. Moreover, don't see any issue with your approach though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This calculation essentially produces the first option you gave.

If you want to select the division of both sums, just do it:

```
SELECT   Emp_key, date_key, ROUND(SUM(Amt_1) / SUM(Amt_2), 4) AS Net_Amt 
FROM     salary
GROUP BY Emp_key,date_key;
```

If you're concerned about `SUM(Amt_2)` being zero, you can still treat if with a `case` statement:

```
SELECT   Emp_key, 
         date_key, 
         CASE WHEN SUM(Amt_2) <> 0 
              THEN ROUND(SUM(Amt_1) / SUM(Amt_2), 4) 
         END AS Net_Amt 
FROM     salary
GROUP BY Emp_key,date_key;
```